# The users page on Data.SE isn't reporting the correct number of saved queries

Tags: bug, data-explorer

According to [this page](https://data.stackexchange.com/users?page=14) on the Data.SE I've got more than a 1200 saved queries on Data.SE. I'm pretty sure this is counting the revisions.

[image]

Comment: It actually is counting what it's supposed to, but the only thing that would explain the count discrepancy between your profile and the number shown there is if you had a ton of hidden queries...Will make a note to look into it more later.

Comment: @TimStone. What's a hidden query?

Comment: That's actually a good question. Queries could be hidden at some point, by some one...and I'm not really sure how that worked. In any case, the only difference I see at the moment between the query that gets the "edited" list for your profile and the one that generates that number is that the profile list only includes query sets where `Hidden = 0`.